# Creating custom Ribbon Tool bar while opening a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a .xlsb workbook with lot of macros. when this workbook is open, 3 new tabs are automatically created.

Normally this code should be inside "ThisWorkbook" sheet, but this is empty. i also searched for this code in all the other modules but i did not find it in any other module as well. is there any way to find where this code resides?

Comment: It's probably not code, it's probably in the definition.  Did you open the .xlsb as a zip file and look at the files there?

Comment: @rory.ap thank you. I zipped it and found a custom UI XML file with the XML code for these tabs. it helped!